# Open Cart SEO URL for category/manufacturer

Tags: seo, opencart

OC 1.5.6

I've installed a module to filter products in categories based on manufacturer.

I'm able to reach every "search result page" at an url like:

```
example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=X&manufacturer=Y
```

I'd like to create a SEO url like:

```
example.com/alias-for-category/alias-for-manufacturer
```

(ex. /bikes/honda or /cars/bmw)

but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried for testing and simplifying to convert just a single url:

```
product/category&path=1&manufacturer=1
```

so I added to `url_alias` a record with this query and keyword

```
cat1-man1
```

then I modified `catalog/common/seo_url.php`

function Index

```
if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
        } 
        //ADDED BELOW CODE TO ROUTE ALL URL
        else {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->get['_route_']) . "'");
            if ($query->num_rows) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = $query->row['query'];
            }
        }
```

and function rewrite

```
if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }                   
            } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                $categories = explode('_', $value);

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                    }                           
                }

                unset($data[$key]);
            }  
            //ADDED CODE BELOW TO CONVERT ALL URL
            else {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['route']) . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }
            }
```

but also this simplified version doesn't work at all, page not found is shown.

What I'm doing wrong? Any tip will be really appreciated

Comment: did you check if it's getting in your `else` condition, maybe its getting in this condition `elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
        } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the custom module I've installed expects the parameter for manufacturer as "manufacturer" instead of "manufacturer_id" so a converted URL like :

```
example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=X&manufacturer_id=Y
```

isn't handled correctly by the module.

**So the answer to my question is : OC does already convert alias-cat/alias-manufacturer to a correct internal URL**

On the other hand OC does not convert URL of the type

```
example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=X&manufacturer_id=Y
```

into SEO friendly URL like:

```
example.com/alias-for-category/alias-for-manufacturer
```

in the menus or links, to do this, modify `catalog/common/seo_url.php` like this:

```
public function rewrite($link) {
    $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

    $url = ''; 

    $data = array();

    parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($data['route'])) {
            if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }                   
            } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                $categories = explode('_', $value);

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                    }                           
                }

                unset($data[$key]);
            }  
            // ADD THIS CODE
            elseif ($key == 'manufacturer_id') {

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'manufacturer_id=" . (int)$value . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                }                           

                unset($data[$key]);
            } 
            // END ADDED CODE----------------
            else {
                   .....
```